# sending an email via curl and stmp not working

Tags: curl, smtp

I'm trying to write a script to send an email using:

```
curl --url 'smtp://smtp.example.com:587' --ssl-reqd \
  --mail-from 'sender@example.com' --mail-rcpt 'recipient@example.com' \
  --upload-file mail.txt --user 'username:password'
```

straight from a resource url: tecadmin.net

im sure curl is installed (via curl --version), im sure my variables are correct as I tested them by logging into my gmail account and yet I get the following error:

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to smtp.google.com port 587 after 289364 ms: Connection timed out
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
--mail-from: command not found
```

my code is as follows:

```
SMTP_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com"

SMTP_PORT="587"

SMTP_USERNAME="*********"

SMTP_PASSWORD="********"

TO="*******@gmail.com"

SUBJECT="TEST"

BODY="THIS IS A TEST"

MESSAGE="$SUBJECT\n\n$BODY"

curl --url "smtp://smtp.google.com:587" --ssl-reqd \
        --mail-from '************@gmail.com' \
        --mail-rcpt "$TO" \
        --user "$SMTP_USERNAME:$SMTP_PASSWORD" \
        --tlsv1.2 \
        -T <(echo -e "$MESSAGE")
```

ive given the file execute permissions and ran it but I'm still getting the error above telling me the --mail-from command isn't found. hows that possible?